# django oauth2 creating application redirect problem

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

when I want to create an application with this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/applications/ , it always redirects me to this address http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/o/applications/ how can I solve it?, note that I don't want to use Django admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily define your application using shell
type: `python manage.py shell` to enter shell then use this to define application:

```
from oauth2_provider.models import Application
Application.objects.create(authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_PASSWORD, client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL)
```